# Is there a way to change floating to whole number in for loop in bash

Tags: bash, double, floating

I have a bash loop that I run to copy 2 files from the hpc to my local drive recursively over the  processors and all the timesteps. On the hpc the timesteps are saved as

> 1 2 3

whereas the bash loop interprets it as

> 1.0 2.0 3.0

probably because of the 0.5 increment. Is there a way to get the $j to be changed to whole number (without the decimal) when running the script?

Script I use:

```
for i in $(seq 0 1 23)
do
    mkdir Run1/processor$i
    for j in $(seq 0 0.5 10);
    do
        mkdir Run1/processor$i/$j
        scp -r xx@login.hpc.xx.xx:/scratch/Run1/processor$i/$j/p Run1/processor$i/$j/
        scp -r xx@login.hpc.xx.xx:/scratch/Run1/processor$i/$j/U Run1/processor$i/$j/
    done
done
```

Result:

```
scp: /scratch/Run1/processor0/1.0/p: No such file or directory
```

The correct directory that exists is

> /scratch/Run1/processor0/1

Thanks!

Comment: replace `$j` by `${j%.0}`

Comment: If you want integers, why are you using an 0.5 increment? If you truncate those to integers, you're going to get each number (except the last) twice: 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ...

Comment: _the bash loop interprets it as_  : I don't understand what you are saying here. `seq` produces strings corresponding to fractional numbers (which you can verify when doing a `echo $j` inside the loop. `bash` itself can't do floats, but this is not relevant here, since you treat all those "numbers" as strings anyway, and never do any arithmetic. The real problem is the use of `seq`, which by definition produces fraction when called in the way you are doing. This is unrelated to bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, yes!

but: Depending on what the end result is.

I will assume you want to floor the decimal number. I can think of 2 options:

1. pipe the number to cut
2. do a little bit of perl

```
for i in $(seq 0 1 23); do
  for j in $(seq 0 0.5 10); do
# pipe to cut
    echo /scratch/Run1/processor$i/$(echo $j | cut -f1 -d".")/U Run1/processor"$i/$j"/
# pipe to perl
    echo /scratch/Run1/processor$i/$(echo $j | perl -nl -MPOSIX -e 'print floor($_);')/U Run1/processor"$i/$j"/
  done
done
```

result:

```
...
/scratch/Run1/processor23/9/U Run1/processor23/9/
/scratch/Run1/processor23/9/U Run1/processor23/9.5/
/scratch/Run1/processor23/9/U Run1/processor23/9.5/
/scratch/Run1/processor23/10/U Run1/processor23/10/
/scratch/Run1/processor23/10/U Run1/processor23/10/
```

edit :

Experimented a litle, found another way:

```
echo /scratch/Run1/processor$i/${j%%.[[:digit:]]}/U Run1/processor"$i/$j"/
```

Comment: This did the work! Thanks!